# Ruby on Rails ajax post failed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

following were my javascript where user post the updates:

```
$('.attachments-container').on('click', '.cover-attachment', function(event) {
                var attachment_id = $(this).parent().find('input[name="product_attachment[id][]"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/products/update_cover",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: attachment_id,
                    complete: function(){
                        console.log('change completed');
                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault();

            })
```

On my routes:

```
resources :products do
        member do
            match "update_cover", via: [:post]
            post "update_cover" => 'products#update_cover'

        end
    end
```

On my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:result, :show]
def update_cover
        @attachment_id = params[:attachment_id]
        render :json => {:status => 'success'}.to_json
    end
end
```

I had no clue where this error comes from: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/products/update_cover"):` Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you run rake routes in your terminal you will see that you do not have a route for products/update_cover. You have - products/:id/update_cover. Since you have defined it as a member route, you need to pass the parent_id as part of the route. Try this

```
url: "/products/" + attachment_id + "update_cover",
```

And you dont need to pass attachment_id in the data hash.

Incidentally, the 2 routes you posted essentially do the same thing. You can lose

```
match "update_cover", via: [:post]
```

Comment: How can I pass it as `/products/update_cover` rather than include the id?

Comment: You'd have to change the route by un-nesting it from products and giving it the product_update_cover name.  It would just be post "product_update_cover" => 'products#update_cover'. And pass the id in the data hash. I'm not sure I'd recommend this option. It's flouting rails convention.  If you play around with configuring the routes and viewing the results by running rake routes, you'll get a feel of how to structure them.